# How to list only files with a specific extended attribute in macOS?

Tags: macos, file-attributes

I have a directory with about 10,000 files and I'm using `ls` to list the files.

However, I want to list only the files that have the `com.example.mycolor` extended attribute set.

What I tried:

```
ls -l@ | grep 'mycolor'
```

But this doesn't work.

For some context, I used this to set the attribute:

```
xattr -w com.example.mycolor booltrue spreadsheet.xls
```

Answer (score 3):

```
ls -l@ | perl -ne '/ccom.example.mycolor/ && $last && print $last; $last = $_'
```

Thanks to this website post titled: [Perl One-Liners Explained, Part VI: Selective printing and deleting of lines](https://catonmat.net/perl-one-liners-explained-part-six)

And even this can be done according to [this answer on the Apple Stack Exchange site](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/324818/40457):

```
find . -xattrname com.example.mycolor
```

Comment: While that post you link to is good, please don’t add comments that should be in the body of your answer. I have edited your answer to provide both solutions. Comments are just disposable and often overlooked if not explicitly dumped after time.